# Migrate RCP project from 3.6 to 4.4

Tags: eclipse, rcp

I am upgrading an RCP project to Eclipse 4 (4.4.2) from Eclipse Helios (3.6.1).
I had a problem with plug-in configuration. Here is the stack trace: http://pastebin.com/SHEY4iYq.

The stack trace told: Import-Package: javax.annotation; version="1.0.0". But i think i already had this library in plug-in dependency. http://prntscr.com/7taz9m

Any solution about this case? Or any suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The Import-Package just says that you need this package. The error is telling you that the javax.annotation import cannot be found when you run the application.

You probably need to update your RCP build to include the javax.annotation plugin (and possibly other plugins). How you do this depends on the type of build you are using.

Comment: thank you for the fast answer. I changed run time environment in run configuration to java 8, somehow it passed this problem. I think i must study eclipse RCP from the beginning.